# How should I configure an object dynamically when using Symfony's DI?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm using a YAML configuration to wire my dependencies, and I need to provide some runtime information to get a useful object back. I was going to run a setter method from my code once the object has been injected, but I Was wondering if there was a better way of doing it (or if there's something I'm missing).

This is the gist of my configuration:

```
services:
    example_object : "myObject"
        arguments : ["%object_parameter1%"] 
parameters:
    object_parameter1 : Some Static Data
    object_parameter2 : #Rutime info required
```

Comment: Specifiy the runtime info, what you need.

Comment: It will be a user ID reference which I will know when asking for the object.

Comment: The current logged in user, or from which source comes the reference?

Comment: In the future, yes, it will be the currently logged in user. I'm going to have to do isolated tests on this module so they will be configured from a php unit test. I should point out that I'm only using DI from symphony for the time being.

Comment: in your config test you can define your parameters, for example an userId. For a complex operation you can manipulate the definition in your testClass: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html

Comment: AFAYK is this the best way to tackle the problem? I'm trying to avoid configuring the container in php, but I will accept "too bad, you have to" as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving the current logged in user in any service, inject the `security.context`. In this case I use setter injection to simply user mock injection.

```
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Foo;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class MyService
{
    private $param;
    private $user;

    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the current logged in user from the security context.
     */
    public function setUserFromContext(SecurityContextInterface $context)
    {
        $this->user = $context->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    /**
     * Set any user object.
     *
     * Usefull for testing, to inject a simple user mock.
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // do something with the user object
    }
}
```

Define the service:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Acme\ExampleBundle\Foo\MyService
        arguments: ["%object_parameter1%"]
        calls:
            - [ setUserFromContext, [@security.context] ]
```

Comment: To be clear, I'm building this to interface with an existing system, and I can't rely on including the security component- hence why I said I'm only using DI from symfony. At the moment I'm not even sure how the user will be represented here. Is there an approach for setting it from a variable rather than feeding in a context?

Comment: MyService is directly dependent on the User. I would aim to practice the Law of Demeter, by removing the SecurityContextInterface dependency. If the solution for fetching the current User object isn't yet known then I'd at the least migrate the code smell into the fetching of the User object and define a User service for inclusion as a dependency to other services.  At least then when you have a preferred solution for fetching the current User object you will have minimal refactoring effort and this will help to keep your code base clean and test friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to add dynamic values directly into the DI configuration. Symfony services configuration is reflected by compiled DI container and recompilation is very heavy operation.

If you do not want to couple your service with Symfony's security system directly, you can add your custom "user provider" service as a dependency. Then you will need to rewrite this service if the source of information will change. It may be also easily mocked.

You can also use a factory to inject a user object instead of user provider service.